# SQL greater than query is returning incorrect results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and looking to expand my skill set considerably. I have created a simple database with two tables,'products' and 'shopping'.

I used the following query to create my first table and values

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE shopping(Product TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Quantity       NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO shopping(Product, Quantity) VALUES ('Jam', 1);
sqlite> INSERT INTO shopping(Product, Quantity) VALUES ('Bread', 2);
sqlite> INSERT INTO shopping(Product, Quantity) VALUES ('Tea', 5); 
sqlite> INSERT INTO shopping(Product, Quantity) VALUES ('Cereal', 1);
```

and the following query to create my second table

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE ProductData(Product TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Price NOT NULL);
sqlite> .import /home/solidsnake/Documents/ProductData.csv ProductData
```

values for this table where imported via a .csv file with

```
sqlite> SELECT Product, Price
...> FROM products;
```

giving the output:

```
Jam,250
Tea,150
Cereal,120
Eggs,170
Cheese,320
Potatoes,80
Treacle,80
Bananas,100
Bread,230
Caviar,1000
```

The main problem I'm now running into is I need to use an SQL query to find out what products in the shop have a cost higher than 120.

After having a thorough search on the internet I found that the correct query to provide me with the correct input is

```
SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE Price > '120';
```

However, this gives me the output:

```
Jam,250
Tea,150
Eggs,170
Cheese,320
Potatoes,80
Treacle,80
Bread,230
```

As you can see, both potatoes and treacle have a price of **80** which is less than **120**. Also caviar is not provided in the output which seems strange since it has a price of **1000**.

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction as to what the problem is with my syntax and why it's producing an incorrect output.

PS: Sorry for the long winded post, but I wanted to provide as much information as possible. I'm new to stackoverflow and have tried to follow the 'How to ask a question' post as closely as possible.

Thanks.

edit: SOLVED

Thanks lad2025.I ended up removing the shopping table and recreating it, incorporating your suggestion. The query now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not compare with string value(use integer):

```
SELECT * FROM "products" WHERE Price > 120; -- instead of '120'
```

String sorting is different than integer, so '80' > '120' is correct
and '1000' < '120' is also correct.

```
SELECT '80' > '120', 80 > 120
-- 1 0

SELECT '1000' > '120', 1000 > 120
-- 0 1
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=f49cd7bea5012f18ba7859a7ff2a4768)**

Plus define Quantity datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE shopping(Product TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Quantity   INT    NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I've compared it with an integer value instead of a string, but the output is now displaying everything in the products table, including those with a price of less than 120.

Comment: @GeorgeStrawbridge You need also to define Quantity datatype

Comment: Appreciate the advice once again. Am I right in thinking I need to remove the shopping table altogether and recreate it? Or is it able to be edited on the fly so to speak?

Comment: @GeorgeStrawbridge It would be interesting to know whether the data type could be converted automatically using some `ALTER TABLE ...` statement.